# Google sheets formula to get the % change of the last 5 rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I´m struggling with a formula in Google Sheets I want to implement. What I want to do is find the % change of the last 5 rows in a table. And everytime a new row gets added, that should again calculate the % change of this last "5 days block" cells.

[My current setup:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8skR.png)

So, as per the attached image, the current % change of the last 5 days should be 9.21% (9202/8425). But tomorrow when a new value gets added on May 4th, for example of $9250, the % change should be 11.11% (the % change of 9250 on May 5th vs 8324.99 on April 29th).

Hope I´ve made myself clear, thanks in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this formula to get the last numeric value in column B.

```
=INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(143^143,B2:B))
```

To get the 5th last value in column B, i.e. the total from 5 days ago we can adjust the same formula.

```
=INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(143^143,B2:B)-4)
```

We can then combine these formulas to get the percent change.

```
=(INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(143^143,B2:B))-INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(143^143,B2:B)-4))/INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(143^143,B2:B)-4)
```

Of course, format the cell with that formula to Percent. (Format>Number>Percent)